# Weird sign in EOM: Centripetal vs. centrifugal term

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, angular-momentum, centrifugal-force

Something goes wrong when I was deriving the equation of motion in Kepler's probelm, as below,

1. *Angular momentum conservation* $L = Mr^2\dot{\theta}^2$.
2. And Lagrangian is $L = \frac{1}{2}M(\dot{r}^2 + r^2\dot{\theta}^2) - V(r)$.

**Method 1** compute $\frac{\partial L}{\partial r} = Mr\dot{\theta}^2 - d_rV = \frac{L^2}{Mr^3}-d_rV$.

however, another way is to rewrite Lagrangian first, $L = \frac{1}{2}M\dot{r}^2+\frac{1}{2}\frac{L^2}{Mr^2} - V(r)$, and then compute the partial derivative w.r.t to $r$ again,

**Method 2** we get different result $\frac{\partial L}{\partial r} = -\frac{L^2}{Mr^3}-d_rV$.

These two should be equal, but there are different with a sign, can somebody tell me where is wrong?

Comment: Related/Duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262183 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83190 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420489 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572604

Comment: I am fully understand, thanks!