# Using EOM in QED Lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, equations-of-motion

Let's have the QED Lagrangian.

$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \bar{\Psi}(i\partial_\mu \gamma^\mu - m)\Psi + g\bar{\Psi}A_\mu \gamma^\mu \Psi.\tag{1}$$

The equations of motion are:

$$ \partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = g\bar{\Psi}\gamma^\nu \Psi \tag{2}$$

and

$$(i\partial_\mu \gamma^\mu - m)\Psi = -g A_\mu \gamma^\mu \Psi.\tag{3}$$

If we use the first EOM and replace the current (in the third term of the $\mathcal{L}$) by the derivative of $F_{\mu\nu}$ we find the following Lagrangian.

$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \bar{\Psi}(i\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu - m)\Psi.\tag{4}$$

We can see that the interacting term between the fermion and the gauge boson disappeared. The main question is **How is possible that two equivalent lagrangians (we can go from one to the other by EOM) have different Feynman diagrams?**

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): Eqs. (2) & (3) seem wrong. For starters, the indices do not match.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/420489/2451

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a step back and look at a Lagrangian from classical mechanics. For example, $$L(x,\dot x)=\tfrac 1 2 m\dot x^2-U(x),$$
but we could choose any Lagrangian here. We can also define an action $S[x(t)]=\int dt\, L(x(t),\dot x(t))$; the action is a [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative), which takes a function as input and outputs a number. Functionals are often indicated with square brackets. In contrast, the Lagrangian is a function. For the Lagrangian $x$ is just an argument (a number) but for the action $x(t)$ is a function (a parametrization). For example, $L(y,z)=\tfrac 1 2m y^2-U(z)$ is the same Lagrangian as in the first equation.

Any relevant Lagrangian obeys a stationary-action principle: whenever the action is minimized it produces equations of motion. We can minimize the action by taking a functional derivative and then setting it to zero. This will result in a function $x_0(t)$ which minimizes the action given some boundary conditions. Formally
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta x(t)}[x_0(t)]=0.$$

Now you are basically asking why $L(x_0(t),\dot x_0(t))$ gives a different result. The answer is that it doesn't make sense to plug $x_0(t)$ back into the Lagrangian and you should not expect the same result at all.