# Can the $\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$ term in canonical energy–momentum tensor be omitted?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem, equations-of-motion

From Noether theory we can define the canonical energy–momentum tensor as
\begin{equation}
T_{\mu\nu}\equiv\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial^\mu\phi)}\partial_\nu\phi-\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}.
\end{equation}
$T_{\mu\nu}$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu}=0.
\end{equation}
For example, $T_{\mu\nu}$ of Dirac field $\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi$ is
\begin{equation}
(T_\text{D})_{\mu\nu}=i\bar{\psi}\gamma_\mu\partial_\nu\psi-\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}.
\end{equation}
But in some$^1$ books and papers, I see the authors omit the $\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$ term in $T_{\mu\nu}$. The reason is that Noether theory holds only "on shell". This means we've used EOM. Thus $\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi=\bar{\psi}\times\text{EOM}=0$ so we omit the $\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$ term.

My question is

1. Can the $\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$ term be omitted? Obviously if we omit the $\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$ term then $T_{\mu\nu}$(made up of the rest term) does not satisfy $\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu}=0$.
2. If the $\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$ term here (for Dirac field) can be omitted. Can this term be omitted for other Lagrangian, for example, the Maxwell Lagrangian $-\frac14F^2$?

---

$^1$ For example https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08113. There is no $\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$ term in (57). Another example is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinfante%E2%80%93Rosenfeld_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), at the end of the "Belinfante–Rosenfeld and the Hilbert energy–momentum tensor" part.

Answer (score 3):

1. The continuity equation $d_{\mu} T^{\mu\nu}\approx 0$ only holds on-shell, so often one is only interested in the [canonical SEM tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Canonical_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) on-shell. Then one can disregard terms that vanish on-shell.
2. For Lagrangian densities that vanish on-shell, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254513/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254513/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Comment: Thank you. Actucally Klein-Gordon Lagragian can be written as $-\frac12\phi\square\phi$, spin 1 field Lagragian can be written as $\frac12A_\mu(\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial^2-\partial^\mu\partial^\nu)A_\nu$. It seems that for spin 0,1/2,1 the $\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$ term in energy–momentum tensor can all be omitted...

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Noether only says that $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$ when the equations of motion are satisfied.  Consequently,
if the $L$ term vanishes when we satisfy the equations of motion (as it does  for the Dirac equation) then we can omit it, and what is left still satisfies $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$.

Comment: Hmm... Is $\partial_\mu(i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\psi)=0$?

Comment: The Dirac action integral  is $\int \bar \psi( \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu+ m)\psi d^dx$, the E of M is $( \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu+ m)\psi =0$, and the derivative of something that is identically zero zero is zero.